# Signup and Login form post data without specifying path in action attribute

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-urls

I just discovered a probable **BUG** in my code that allows user to signup or login  **action** attribute is blank.

Here is what i mean

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="supernova"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>SignIn</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/signup/css/1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/signup/css/2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/signup/css/3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/signup/css/4.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/signup/css/5.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/signup/css/6.css">

<script src="/static/signup/js/1.js"></script>
<script src="/static/signup/js/2.js"></script>
<script src="/static/signup/js/3.js"></script>
<script src="/static/signup/js/4.js"></script>
<script src="/static/signup/js/5.js"></script>
<script src="/static/signup/js/6.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form class="jotform-form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form_230023299150548" id="230023299150548" accept-charset="utf-8" autocomplete="on">
  {% csrf_token %}
  
  <div role="main" class="form-all">
    <ul class="form-section page-section">
      <li id="cid_60" class="form-input-wide" data-type="control_head">
        <div class="form-header-group  header-small">
          <div class="header-text httal htvam">
            <h3 id="header_60" class="form-header" data-component="header">SignIn</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="form-line jf-required" data-type="control_textbox" id="id_64">
        <label class="form-label form-label-left" id="label_64" for="input_64"> Username
          <span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div id="cid_64" class="form-input jf-required">
          {{form.username}}
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="form-line jf-required" data-type="control_fullname" id="id_66">
        <label class="form-label form-label-left form-label-auto" id="label_66" for="first_66">Password
          <span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div id="cid_66" class="form-input jf-required">
          <div data-wrapper-react="true">
            <span class="form-sub-label-container" style="vertical-align:top" data-input-type="first">
              {{form.password}}
            </span>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="form-line" data-type="control_button" id="id_76">
        <div id="cid_76" class="form-input-wide">
          <div data-align="center" class="form-buttons-wrapper form-buttons-center   jsTest-button-wrapperField"><button id="input_76" type="submit" class="form-submit-button submit-button jf-form-buttons jsTest-submitField" data-component="button" data-content="">Submit</button></div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>/
  
  <!-- <div class="formFooter-heightMask"></div>
  <div class="formFooter f6 branding21"></div> -->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the opening form tag, i am yet to specify the path to login view and yet i am able to login. Same thing happens with Signup Page

here is my views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html", {})


def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Signup(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST["username"]
            first_name = request.POST["first_name"]
            last_name = request.POST["last_name"]
            email = request.POST["email"]
            password = request.POST["password"]
            password2 = request.POST["password2"]

            if "@yahoo.com" or "@ymail.com" in email:
                user = User.objects.create_user(
                    username=username,
                    first_name=first_name,
                    last_name=last_name,
                    password=password,
                    email=email,
                )
                user.save()
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(
                    request, "Account Created successfully for " + username
                )
                return redirect(index)
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(
                    username=username,
                    first_name=first_name,
                    last_name=last_name,
                    password=password,
                    email=email.lower(),
                )
                user.save()
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(
                    request, "Account Created successfully for " + username
                )
                return redirect(index)
    else:
        form = Signup()
    return render(request, "accounts/register.html", {"form": form})


def signin(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(index)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Signin(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST["username"]
            password = request.POST["password"]

            user = User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()
            if user:
                get_user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
                check_pass = check_password(password, get_user[0].password)
                if not check_pass:
                    messages.error(request, "incorrect password")
                    return redirect(signin)
                else:
                    login(request, get_user[0])
                    return redirect(index)
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid User")
                return redirect(signin)
    else:
        form = Signin()
        return render(request, "accounts/login.html", {"form": form})


def signout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect(index)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("books/", views.books, name="book"),
    path("test/", views.test, name="test"),
    path("test1/", views.test1, name="test1"),
    path("borrow/", views.borrow, name="borrow"),
    path("profile/<int:pk>/", views.profile, name="profile"),
]
```

What i want to know is if it is a bug and how i can fix it or if it is a norm for django because this is the first time i am experiencing such.

Comment: Just put the directory of the .py to your empty ```action=""```.

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

On your views page you already made a statement checking the type of request made by the page. The user authentication took place when it got to: if request.method == POST. At that point, your page is making the post request